# Resize Bitmap on GPU

Tags: java, android, bitmap, renderscript

I'd like to be able resize bitmaps using the GPU on Android (4.0+).

I've been using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`  for now, but I'd like something that runs much faster than that is capable of.

My research has indicated that `RenderScript` might be a viable way of doing this, but I haven't found much documentation around it, and I'm not really sure how I'd go about implementing my own resize script.

Is there a way to do this in Java that is faster than `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`, or is `RenderScript` my only choice; and if so what's the best way to approach writing the script?

---

Edit:

My current process is to load the original image off of disk using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`, resize using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` and then finally I write the resized image to disk using `bitmap.compress()`

Comment: why do you want resized Bitmap? just to draw it on the screen or to write it as an image file ?

Comment: Consider straight OpenGL? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

Comment: @pskink: To write to an image file

Comment: tried Bitmap.create() and drawing the orig Bitmap on it using the scaled Canvas?